# Checking Root Keys in Cerberus

Tags: python, cerberus

I have a data structure that looks like this with `name` being an 
arbitrary string that cannot be certain values (`src`)

```
 {
  'name' : 'stringvalue',
  'src'  : 'who cares this is wrong'
 }
```

I'd like cerberus to check that the keys are anything but `src` or `alsoBad`, but all the schema examples I see seem to require that I specify the format for a given name.

I've tried this:

```
 def check_data(type_data):
    val = cerberus.Validator()
    val.allow_unknown={'forbidden' : ['src','alsoBad']}

    val.validate(type_data,{})
```

With the thought that the empty schema would cause the `allow_unknown` to go to work.  But this does not find the problem.

Then I tried:

```
 def check_data(type_data):
    val = cerberus.Validator()
    val.allow_unknown=

    val.validate(type_data,{'any_field':{'forbidden' : ['src','alsoBad']}})
```

But this also failed to catch the problem.

How do I check the first level keys in a dict when they could be anything?

Comment: Clearly the second one is checking that the data in the unknown fields are not `src` or `alsoBad`, but still don't see how to check the field names themselves.

Comment: You should give at least one valid and one invalid example of a document as well as the schema you got so far. i have the impression that you're overcomplicating your task.

Answer (score 0):

I have punted and just done it with code:

```
def check_data(type_data):
     bad_field=set(['src','alsoBad']) & set(type_data.keys())
     if bad_field:
          raise ValueError(f'Cannot have field {bad_field}'
```